# Hibernate @Version conflict with @Audited (probably)

Tags: java, hibernate

I add to my Entity

> @Version
>       @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
>       @Column(name = "version")
>       private Date version;

and something strange happend. When i update, hibernate tells thath key already exists. How @version filed affect my Entity? I have no idea why it happend. When i remove this @version field everything works. I also use @Audited annotation.

My Entity:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1636824190907788517L;
@Id
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id")
private UUID id;
@Version
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "version")
private Date version;
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name = "user", nullable = false)
private User user;
@Column(name = "purpose", length = 100)
protected String comment;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinColumn(name = "eq_id", nullable = false)
protected BasicEquipment equip;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinColumn(name = "eq_id2", nullable = false)
protected BasicEquipment equip2;
```

Error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement (...)
>       
> org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(Standaorg.hibernate.engine.jdbc.sporg.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatch
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTra
>   Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_entity"

Comment: Saying "everything works when I remove @Version" is a bit like saying "I can not reach the back of my car while driving, but when I remove my seat belt, everything works". Do not fight symptoms, fight the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this solution?

http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/jpa-entity-versioning-version-and-optimistic-locking

> Under some circumstances, problems may occur when versioned updates
>   are used together with batch updates. It has happened to me in the
>   past with a given version of Oracle 11g and Hibernate, for example.
>   The Oracle JDBC driver was not able to extract the correct number of
>   updated rows count in JDBC batch statements execution.
>
> If you are also facing this problem, you may check if you have set the
>   Hibernate property hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data to true. When
>   this setting is true, Hibernate will use batch updates even for
>   updates that are made against versioned data, ie. updates that need to
>   use the updated rows count in order to check for concurrent updates.
>   Since the JDBC driver may not return the correct updated rows count,
>   Hibernate will not be able to detect if concurrent updates actually
>   happened. The default value for this setting in Hibernate is false, so
>   it will not use batch updates when it detects that versioned data
>   updates are going to be executed in a given flush operation.
>
> This is of course a specific scenario with Oracle 11g that is easily
>   worked around, as we have just seen.

Comment: I set additional property for hibernate but it doesnt work. Now i assume that it wasny error with duplicated key but conflicy between audited and version...and still i have the same errror about duplicate key